# Zoho desk invalid oauth

Tags: zoho

I am testing out Zoho desk API. I have set up a dummy client in zoho console dashboard and using the self client option to generate a oauth_token. However when I try to use it, it always return an error code 401 with error code "INVALID_OAUTH". 
I have checked for characters, and using it before even one minute of generation. Can somebody please help me with this?

```
    {   
url = "https://desk.zoho.in/api/v1/organizations"
payload = ""
headers = {
'Authorization': "Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.XXXXXabdbd925112
 4ff.44d3eccd1e1a03bd25db1016f0f13322"
   }
}
```

Response

```
{
"errorCode": "INVALID_OAUTH",
"message": "The OAuth Token you provided is invalid."
```

}

Comment: your oauth has expired you need to generate a new one again

Comment: Thanks for replying!
I actually solved it. It wasn't expired, I was using `.in` domain instead of using `.com` one.